# I want the receiver to automatically execute a command upon any git push

Tags: git

I have a git server which I want to run automatically CI tests upon any push request.
how do I hook a command to git?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Server-Side Hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/ch7-3.html#Server-Side-Hooks).

Comment: More precisely a post-receive hook, I think.